# What is the reason for "declaration does not declare anything" error?

Tags: c++

If you have a class called 'Rock', and you do something like :-

```
int main()
{
    Rock;
}
```

why do you get **"declaration does not declare anything"** error ?

Shouldn't it just call the default constructor and create the object at that moment?

Ofcourse I won't be able to use that object and it will get destroyed when it will go out of scope of the function, but why not creating it at all?

In some other programming languages like java, variables are not compulsory. you can do something like **new Rock()** and you will be fine.

I know it isn't of any use but I want to clear my confusion.

Comment: Hint: it's similar to `int;`

Comment: It would be invalid in Java too ("error: not a statement").

Comment: What you're describing is Rock() not Rock, and in my compiler at least, it constructs and immediately destructs. It's not part of the scope. It's not completely useless: this is one way (not the best) to control and ensure initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Rock` is just the name of the class.  There is no variable name declared.  To call a constructor/create an object, you need to declare the name of a variable:  `Rock r;`

This creates an object on the stack that will get destroyed when it goes out of scope

Comment: I know how c++ works but still I would like to ask this for clarification : **r** is a variable of type **Rock**. Isn't it is just a variable with no value? You did not created the object like this - **Rock r()**. Still this works and the object is created. How?

Comment: @Raj - that IS the way C++ works.  `Rock r;`  creates an instance of `Rock` on the stack and calls the default constructor.  You don't need the () in C++

Answer (score 1):

```
Rock;
```

This instantiation code is wrong.

If it has to call default constructor you have to name the object as follows.

```
Rock rd;
```

In C++ `Rock` is a custom type.

So to define the variable of type Rock, you have to follow the syntax as follows

```
Typename variableName
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, calling `new Rock();` will create a temporary object which might get garbage collected right away since it's not bound to a reference.
In C++, you can do the same thing with `Rock{};`, except now you have the guarantee that the object will be destroyed right away

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the constructor use

```
Rock( )
```

Though I don't see much use for what you're trying to do here.
You're basically just stating a type without an actual object.

```
Rock *someRock = new Rock( );
```

Is legit in C++ as well as it creates an object on the heap rather than the stack.
 ( Note you have to free the memory once the object is no longer needed with `delete someRock;` )

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b29301cb6e20ea99)

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
Rock();
```

But what's the goal of that ?

Comment: Suppose Rock has a logger or needs to load some shared libraries, and it uses lazy initialization, but your application needs to be immediately responsive to a request, so it forces the first-time initialization.

Comment: yeah maybe. Sounds like a bad design at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

To make this a declaration or an expression you have two posiibilities. The first one is indeed a declaration

```
int main()
{
    class Rock;
}
```

This declaration declares (or redeclares) class Rock in the scope of function main.

And the second one creates a temporary objects of the class calling its default constructor

```
int main()
{
    Rock();
}
```

Constructors are called using the function call syntax.

Take into account that in C++ you also may use operator new. However the value returned by the operator should be assigned to a pointer. Otherwise there will be a memory leak. The C++ does not have a garbage collector.

So insetad of

```
new Rock();
```

you should write

```
Rock *r = new Rock();
```

Or you may even redeclare name `Rock` the following way

```
Rock *Rock = new class Rock();
```